# 3-tier Registration using PHP

Tags: php, session, registration

Ok,these are my requirements: a registration page should be there to get username and password,which on submit,should redirect to another registration form,to get his personal details,which inturn on submit,should go to another reg form to get his academic details...

Now,only after the personal info is entered into db,the academic details should be entered,and only after that,the username and password should be entered...

If any of the insertion is failed to execute,the entire process should be rolled back,and user should not be registered...

I know i need to use sessions,but i dont know how...help???

Comment: `Step 1:`: Start coding; `Step 2:` Don't know what it does? [Google It](http://www.google.com/); `Step 3:` Show your code here and ask for help to fix errors.

Comment: @Syed Qarib i need a procedure to start....and i ve googled it.Not found anything..i need a plan to start.

Comment: Try using PHP Sessions to pass the data to each registration step.

Comment: nice instructions. you want us all to do this? how much?

Comment: You can done this task via jQuery easily

Answer (score 1):

I've used this kinda system before and it doesn't require the usage of sessions. It just simply keeps the form data at each step.

The issue would be if two users attempted to register the same username, it does not reserve usernames. If the first user completed step one, it doesn't mean it prevents a second user to registering and finishing.

Consider the following step:

```
<form method="post" action="register.php">
    <?php
        if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
            echo '<input type="text" name="username">' .
                 '<input type="text" name="password">' .
                 '<input type="submit"></form>';
            exit;
        }
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="username" value="' . htmlentities($_POST['username']) . '">' .
             '<input type="hidden" name="password" value="' . htmlentities($_POST['password']) . '">';
        if (empty($_POST['dob'])) {
            echo '<input type="text" name="dob">' .
                 '<input type="submit"></form>';
            exit;
        }
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="dob" value="' . htmlentities($_POST['dob']) . '">';
        if (empty($_POST['grades'])) {
            echo '<input type="grades">' .
                 '<input type="submit"></form>';
            exit;
        }
        //$_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['dob'], and $_POST['grades'] can now be processed here
```

Let's walk through it. Upon loading this page, we can see that POST[username] and POST[password] are going to be empty. A form for those two text fields will be made.

When the user submits the form, the text fields won't be made, but instead two hidden elements containing the previously entered data will be present in the form. The next step (dob) will show.

Continuing on, that will also be transformed into a hidden element. Then finally, when all the data is in, you can process all the data at once.

So essentially it looks like this at each step:

```
 Step 1                          Step 2                          Step 3
+----------+---------+          +----------+---------+          +----------+---------+
| username | textbox |          | username | hidden  |          | username | hidden  |
+----------+---------+   -->    +----------+---------+          +----------+---------+
| password | textbox |          | password | hidden  |   -->    | password | hidden  |
+----------+---------+          +----------+---------+          +----------+---------+
| button   | submit  |          | dob      | textbox |          | dob      | hidden  |
+----------+---------+          +----------+---------+          +----------+---------+
                                | button   | submit  |          | grades   | textbox |
                                +----------+---------+          +----------+---------+
                                                                | button   | submit  |
                                                                +----------+---------+
```

Comment: thanks....i will consider it